# Limit size byte[] Java android

Tags: java, android, size, byte, limit

I have to fill a byte[] in my Android application. Sometime, this one is bigger than 4KB.
I initialize my byte[] like this :

```
int size = ReadTools.getPacketSize(ptr.dataInputStream);
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[size];
```

Here, my size = 22625. But when I fill up my byte[] like this :

```
while (i != size) {
myByteArray[i] = ptr.dataInputStream.readByte();
i++;
}
```

But when I print the content of my byte[], I have a byte[] with size = 4060.
Does Java split my byte[] if this one is bigger than 4060 ? And if yes, how can I have a byte[] superior to 4060 ?

Here is my full code:

```
 public class ReadSocket extends Thread{
        DataInputStream inputStream;
        BufferedReader reader;
        GlobalContent ptr;
        public ReadSocket(DataInputStream inputStream, GlobalContent ptr)
        {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
            this.ptr = ptr;
        }

        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            try {
                ptr.StatusThreadReadSocket = 1;
                while(ptr.dataInputStream.available() == 0)
                {
                    if(ptr.StatusThreadReadSocket == 0)
                    {
                        ptr.dataInputStream.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(ptr.StatusThreadReadSocket == 1)
                {
                    int end = ReadTools.getPacketSize(ptr.dataInputStream);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[end];
                    while (i != end) {
                       buffer[j] = ptr.dataInputStream.readByte();
                      i++;
                       j++;
               }
                ptr.StatusThreadReadSocket = 0;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
...
}
```

Comment: What is the "end" variable and what value does it contain?

Comment: Sorry. It was not "end" but the "size" value.

Comment: And you are printing out the "size" value to the console when you debug to make sure it's the size expected? The buffer in question is initialised as shown in the first section of code, right? I'm not familiar with ReadTools, hence these questions.

Comment: Yes my "size" value is equal to 22625. My bad, I made a mistake when I copied my code. It was not "buffer" value in the loop but "myByteArray".

Comment: Just checking.  Have you tried the "read()" method where you specify how much data to read at a time?

Comment: All the requests response I receive are good but when this one is superior to 4060, the rest of the response is missing. I have read something here : [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-is-maximum-size-of-byte-variables/td-p/247636/page/2). But I don't know if it is relevant.

Comment: Must be some kind of buffer then that's interfering with you. I've not been able to recreate the issue at all.

Comment: If you put more than 4060 bytes in your byte[], you can print all of your bytes ?

Comment: It's in your interest to write the best question you can. What's missing: 1) Some context 2) The snippet can't be run 3) Careful description of the bug, and how you obtain and *measure* it 4) Unneeded things: `inputStream`, `reader` and `j`. Guessing is the worst way to fix bugs, anyway either you improve your question, or the only thing that can be said is `getPacketSize` returns `4060` (I assume that you read this value by `buffer.length` and this really can't be changed after initialization, and you state you don't reassign the reference

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't split anything. You should post the minimal code which reproduces your error, and tell where `ReadTools` comes from.

There are two options here:

1. `ReadTools.getPacketSize()` returns `4096`
2. You inadevertedly reassign `myByteArray` to another array

You should really post your full code and tell what library you use. Likely, it will have a method like

```
read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length);
```

Which will save you some typing and also give better performance if all you need is bulk reading the content of the input in memory

Comment: ReadTools.getPacketSize() returns 22625. myByteArray is not reassign to another array. I posting my full code right now.